# how to redirect rest service from post to get

Tags: java, rest, redirect

I have written the code to redirect one rest service to another rest service .In SubmitId() method , i am redirecting another rest service( getLicense() and getError()) and i am unable to redirect it.Please help me out..(i am using JAXRS)

```
 @Path("/resource")
 public class DAMLicenseResource {
 @POST
    @Path("/submittree")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public Response SubmitId(ArrayList<String> selectedIds) throws JAXBException, IOException, URISyntaxException{  
    DAMLicenseService damLicenseService = new DAMLicenseService();
    DAMLicenseOutput damLicenseOutput = damLicenseService.dupSubmittedId(selectedIds);


    if(damLicenseOutput.isError()){
     java.net.URI location1 = new java.net.URI("/DAMLicenseTool/damlicense/resource/error");
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(location1).build();
    }
    else{
        java.net.URI location1 = new java.net.URI("/DAMLicenseTool/damlicense/resource/download");
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(location1).build();   

    }
 }



@POST
@Path("/download")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response getLicense(){
    System.out.println("response api");
    File file = new File("license.txt");
    //write to this file
    try {
        System.out.println("response api");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        fileWriter.write("license");
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    //System.out.println("response api");
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=\"license.txt\"");
    return response.build();
}
@POST
@Path("/error")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response getErrorMsg(){
    System.out.println("error");
    return Response.status(200).entity("failed").build();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all Redirects are not right in REST, REST should not dictate the flow, try other ways to call GET from POST.

```
java.net.URI location = new java.net.URI("../download");
```

temporarily try this, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give the complete path `/DAMLicenseTool/damlicense/resource/error` just give the URI starting from the Controller class `Path`

```
URI uri = new URI("/resource/error");
return Response.temporaryRedirect(uri).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

return "redirect:/secondUrl";
or used Httpclient  for call second URL